# UL - with arrows between the LI - remove unnecessary arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

#**I edit the question:**#

I have attached the html:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <ul id="myUL">
        <li id="li-1" class="myLI"></li>
        <li id="li-2" class="myLI"></li>
        <li id="li-2.1" class="myLI"></li>
        <li id="li-2.2" class="myLI"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My UL is formatted dynamically, based on what comes back from the DB.

*#-------------------------#*

I have a UL, in which all the LIs within it are linked by an arrow.

In addition, I have LIs that consist of several LIs that are their subcategory, and when clicked on, the LIs subcategory - will go from dispaly: none mode, to display: inline-block mode.

My problem is when I have an LI that consists of several LIs, but is located at the end of the UL.

According to my CSS, after this LI, an arrow will appear, because basically, there is another LI in UL, it is just doesn't appear...

I have attached a picture that illustrates this.
[image]
As long as the LI that contains some LI is in the middle of the UL- everything is fine (like example A).
Once it's at the end of the UL (as in example B), I have an "unnecessary" arrow, which I would like not to show now, but only when my all LI are in display: inline-block.

I also attached my CSS.

```
ul#myUL {
  list-style: none;
  margin:auto;
}
li.myLI {

  display:inline-block;
  xpadding: 10px 25px;
  xborder: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 25px;
  position: relative;
}
li.myLI:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 50%;
}
li.myLI:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 0 7px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
  right: -50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

div.mainDiv {
  display:flex;
  width:60%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

I will really appreciate your help to resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: For the heck of it, replace above with `li.myLI:before` and `li.myLI:after` respectively, and add `li.myLI:last-of-type:before { display: none; }` and `li.myLI:last-of-type:after { display: none; }`

Comment: @user4642212 - I added the html

Comment: @Benny - I'm not sure what did you mean.

Comment: I checked again, and it's impossible to achieve what you expect with CSS only. You need jQuery or JS manipulation.

Comment: @Benny - OK, I can use JS / Jquery, But how do I do that?

Comment: Please share also your JS that handles the clicking of `li` elements that shows/hides the sub-category elements. Then I'll try and add my suggested manipulation on top of it.